# NLP: How to tell wether a text is talking about which topic

Tags: python, django

I am a noob in python I was just making a website for studying for children so, I wanted the student to enter their response to a question and then their text response is reviewed and then it checks whether the child has given a response on a particular topic and whether the answer talks about a few key points, so how do I make it and implement it using Django, btw I started web dev a week ago so I am very new to this. Please help me!
thank you !!

Comment: You picked one of the hardest topics in programming. Understanding text is really hard. There are libraries to help you but in general this seems tricky  and I wouldnt suggest it as a starter project. Please dont ask questions like that, show us some code of what you tried so far.

Comment: yes, it's very hard sorry for asking without code as I don't have written any, I was asking for advice thanks for the advice though it is very hard but this is not a project but a task so I have to do it in like 2 months I know google has NLP API but I thought of making my own anyways thanks allot!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/). It will help you understand how django works, and the tutorial could lead you close to your need.

Comment: thanks for the answer i need to know is this possible through NLP

Comment: Django is responsible for building a webapp, it is independent from doing NLP (you can combine both).